# Any suggestions on how to romantically describe a woman's brown hair?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, compound-adjectives

Does anyone know a heartfelt, romantic way to describe the brown hair of a woman/girl? For now, all I have is "silky brown hair," but it just doesn't flow in my poem. This is not official, but I'm doing something along the lines of:

"I look into her diamond eyes and touch her silky brown hair."

I am open to any suggestions. If you think that "silky" is fine, please let me know. If not, please suggest something else. Even if I don't agree with your word choices, anything helps. Perhaps your idea will spark a new one! Compound words and phrases are acceptable. =)

Comment: Maybe put this on Writing.SE?

Comment: @Naomi Thank you for responding! I just want to get some suggestions. Thanks again, and God bless you and your family! =)

Comment: I have seen 'chestnut', but that may make people think of a horse.